# Why ++++i is the undefined behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, c++03, c++98

I just read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735). Now I know why `i = i++` is an UB.

But I don't know why `++++i` is an UB too.

For example,

```
int i = 2;
++++i;
```

I think the value of `i` should be 4. Isn't this a defined behavior? (I'm talking about C++98 and C++03)

Comment: Then don't tag C. It's not UB, it's simply ill-formed in C.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I *thought* (and I do seem to be dreaming a lot these days), `++++i` was UB up to and not including C++11.

Comment: @Bathsheba - It was. But `++i` is not an lvalue in C. So we don't reach UB, as a compiler error hits us in the face.